# Is there a restriction on recipe/package names in Yocto?

Tags: yocto

I am trying to add a new recipe to a project and it seems to work when it's called `foobar` but not when it is called `foo_bar`. I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.7/ref-manual/ref-manual.html).

Are there any restrictions on what a name can look like?

Comment: yes it is reserved, I think you can't use spaces, special characters & uppercase either but you can use "-" dash.

Comment: The "_" character is used at the end of the recipe name, to specify the version (e.g. `foobar_1.2.bb`). The "-" can be used inside the name. It is also common to make a bbappend file with a "%" symbol to apply to all versions : `foobar_%.bbappend`